# SQL check if group contains NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any function to check if a column in a group contains a NULL, alternatively how would I solve this? Example below of data structure.

```
id | value
----------
1  | NULL
1  | 56
2  | 98
2  | 14
```

Result:

```
id | value
----------
1  | 1
2  | 0
```

Comment: Thanks for showing data and expected results.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

try

```
select id, 
       count(*) - count(value) as null_value_count
from your_table
group by id
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4a482/2)

Comment: +1 for precise answer.....But, could you explain bit about count(*) - count(value)?...I'm confused in that line....

Comment: @LolCoder: `count(value)` only counts non-null values, `count(*)` also counts nulls

Comment: +1 for the SQLFiddle demo.  I'd seen jsFiddle, but never SQLFiddle.  Nice!  :)

Answer (score 15):

Another possibility which doesn't use the fact that `count(value)` ignores `NULL` values:

```
select id, 
       sum(case when value is null then 1 else 0 end) as null_count
from your_table
group by id;
```

Comment: Great solution, concise and understandable.